# How to do a join using awk

Tags: awk

Here is my Input file

```
Identifier Relation
A           1
A           2
A           3
B           2
B           3
C           1
C           2
C           3
```

I want to join this file to itself based on the "Relation" field.
Sample Output file

```
A 1 C 1
A 2 B 2
A 2 C 2
B 2 C 2
A 3 B 3
A 3 C 3
B 3 C 3
```

I used the following awk script: 
`awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; next} { for (k in a) if (a[k]~$2) print a[k],$0}' input input > output`

However, I had to do another awk step to delete lines which did a join with itself i.e, A 1 A 1 ; B 2 B 2 etc.

The second issue with this file is it prints both directions of the join, thus
A 1 C 1 is printed along with C 1 A 1 on another line. 
Both these lines display the same relation and I would NOT like to include this.I want to see just one or the other i.e, "A 1 C 1" or "C 1 A 1" not both. 
Any suggestions/directions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an awk-only solution:

```
awk 'NR>1{ar[$2]=(ar[$2]$1);}\
    END{ for(key in ar){\
        for(i=1; i<length(ar[key]); i++) {\
            for(j=i+1; j<length(ar[key])+1; j++) {\
                print substr(ar[key],i,1), key, substr(ar[key],j,1), key;\
            }\
        }\
    }}' infile
```

Each number in the second column of the `input` serves as a key of an awk-array. The value of the corresponding array-element is a sequence of first-column letters (e.g., array[1]=ABC).

Then, we built all two-letter combinations for each sequence (e.g., "ABC" gives "AB", "AC" and "BC")

Output:

```
A 1 C 1
A 2 B 2
A 2 C 2
B 2 C 2
A 3 B 3
A 3 C 3
B 3 C 3
```

Note:

- If a number occurs only once, no output is generated for this number.
- The order of output depends on the order of input. (No sorting of letters!!). That is if the second input line was `C 1`, then `array[1]="CAB"` and the first output line would be `C 1 A 1`
- First line of input is ignored due to `NR>1`

Answer (score 2):

alternative solution using awk with join and sort support

```
$ join -j 2 <(sort -k2 -k1,1 file){,} 
| awk '$2!=$3 && !($3 FS $2 in a){a[$2 FS $3]; print$2,$1,$3,$1}'
A 1 C 1
A 2 B 2
A 2 C 2
B 2 C 2
A 3 B 3
A 3 C 3
B 3 C 3
```

create the cross product, eliminate the diagonal and one of the symmetrical pairs.

Answer (score 1):

There is surely a solution with awk only, but I'm going to propose a solution using awk and sort because I think it's quite simple and does not require storing the entire file content in awk variables. The idea is as follows:

- rewrite the input file so that the "relation" field is first (`A 1` -> `1 A`)
- use `sort -n` to put together all lines with same "relation"
- use awk to combine consecutive lines having the same "relation"

That would translate to something like:

```
awk '{print $2 " " $1}' input | sort -n | 
  awk '{if ($1==lastsel)printf " "; else if(lastsel) printf "\n"; lastsel=$1; printf "%s %s", $2, $1;}END{if(lastsel)printf"\n"}'
A 1 C 1
A 2 B 2 C 2
A 3 B 3 C 3
```

---

EDIT: If you want only one i-j relation per line:

```
awk '{print $2 " " $1}' input | sort -n |
  awk '$1!=rel{rel=$1;item=$2;next;} {printf "%s %s %s %s\n", item, rel, $2, $1;}'
A 1 C 1
A 2 B 2
A 2 C 2
A 3 B 3
A 3 C 3
```

Note the following limitations with this solution:

- In case a given n has only one entry, nothing will be output (no output such as `D 1`)
- All relations always have the lexicographically first item in the first column (e.g. `A 1 C 1` but never `B 1 C 1`)

Comment: Thanks much for the reply @secolive!!! However, I wanted my output to be as below: A 1 C 1; A 2 B 2; A 2 C 2; B 2 C 2; etc. Thus each combination on a different line, not appended together in a single line.